# Как провалидировать селекты?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

в *зависимости* от выбора радио

---

выбрали **У отделение**

если без выбора в селекте

и кликаем далее - то показываем текст с ошибкой под селектом
(типа сделайте выбор)
_______________________________________________________________-

выбрали **на почту**

если без выбора в селекте

кликаем далее - показываем текст с ошибкой под селектом
(типа сделайте выбор)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      $('select[name="department"]').select2({
        placeholder: $(this).data('placeholder'),
        language: "uk"
      }).on('select2:open', function(e) {
        let textPlaceholder = $(this).data('search');
        $('.select2-search input').prop('focus', false);
        $(this).data('select2').$dropdown.find(':input.select2-search__field').attr('placeholder', textPlaceholder);
      });
      
      // validation

      $('form').validate({
        rules: {
          name: {
            required: true,
          },
          department: {
            required: true,
          }
        },
        messages: {
          name: "Поле обязальное",
        },

      });
    })
```

```css
.block__box {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

input {
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

input.error {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form action="#" name='test'>
     <div class="reg__grid">
       <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="nameііі">
     </div>

     <div class="block__wrap">

       <input id="b_1" type="radio" checked class="block__input" name="place">
       <label for="b_1" class="block__label">
         <span class="block__title">У отделение</span>
       </label>
       <div class="block__box">
         <select class="city__select" name="department" data-placeholder="Выберете отделение" data-search="Поиск">
           <option></option>
           <option>отделение № 1 ул. Старо 11</option>
           <option>отделение № 2 ул. Старо 11</option>
           <option>отделение № 3 ул. Старо 11</option>
           <option>отделение № 4 ул. Старо 11</option>
         </select>
       </div>

       <input id="b_2" type="radio" class="block__input" name="place">
       <label for="b_2" class="block__label block__label--inner">
         <span class="block__title">На почту</span>
       </label>
       <div class="block__box">
         <select class="city__select" name="department" data-placeholder="Выберите почтомат" data-search="Поиск">
           <option></option>
           <option>Поштомат № 1 ул. Старо 11</option>
           <option>Поштомат № 2 ул. Стар 11</option>
           <option>Поштомат № 3 ул. Старо 11</option>
           <option>Поштомат № 4 ул. Старо 11</option>
         </select>
       </div>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="reg__next">Дальше </button>
   </form>
   
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибку под селектом сделаете сами (метод плагина гуглится за секунду)

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('select[name="department"]').select2({
        placeholder: $(this).data('placeholder'),
        language: "uk"
      }).on('select2:open', function(e) {
        let textPlaceholder = $(this).data('search');
        $('.select2-search input').prop('focus', false);
        $(this).data('select2').$dropdown.find(':input.select2-search__field').attr('placeholder', textPlaceholder);
      });


$('input[type=radio]').on('change',function(){
$('select').removeAttr('name');
$(this).next().next().find('select').attr('name','department');



$('[name="department"]').rules('remove',  'required')

$('label[id=department-error]').remove();

$('form').validate();
$('[name="department"]').rules('add',{required:true});



})


      // validation
      $('form').validate({
        rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        },
                department: {
        required: true
        }
 
        },
        messages: {
          name: "Поле обязальное",
        },

      });
    })
```

```css
.block__box {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

input {
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

input.error {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <form action="#" name='test'>
     <div class="reg__grid">
       <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="nameііі">
     </div>
     <div class="block__wrap">

       <input id="b_1" type="radio" checked class="block__input" name="place">
       <label for="b_1" class="block__label">
         <span class="block__title">У отделение</span>
       </label>
       <div class="block__box">
         <select class="city__select " data-placeholder="Выберете отделение" data-search="Поиск" name="department">
           <option></option>
           <option>отделение № 1 ул. Старо 11</option>
           <option>отделение № 2 ул. Старо 11</option>
           <option>отделение № 3 ул. Старо 11</option>
           <option>отделение № 4 ул. Старо 11</option>
         </select>
       </div>

       <input id="b_2" type="radio" class="block__input" name="place">
       <label for="b_2" class="block__label block__label--inner">
         <span class="block__title">На почту</span>
       </label>
       <div class="block__box">
         <select class="city__select"  name="department" data-placeholder="Выберите почтомат" data-search="Поиск">
           <option></option>
           <option>Поштомат № 1 ул. Старо 11</option>
           <option>Поштомат № 2 ул. Стар 11</option>
           <option>Поштомат № 3 ул. Старо 11</option>
           <option>Поштомат № 4 ул. Старо 11</option>
         </select>
       </div>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="reg__next">Дальше </button>
   </form>

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую доработать